# Does CakePHP officially support SQLite3?

Tags: php, cakephp, sqlite

If so, how well? I can't seem to find any up to date information.

Comment: Seems like a question to ask the CakePHP folk.

Comment: @Jared if only anyone used the http://ask.cakephp.org site :P

Comment: Is that a StackExchange site? It looks like one...

Comment: @Jared It is a clone they made (that no one uses).

Comment: I would say so. Too bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1075/DataSources

> DataSources are the link between models and the source of data that models represent. In many cases, the data is retrieved from a relational database such as MySQL, PostgreSQL or MSSQL. CakePHP is distributed with several database-specific datasources (see the dbo_* class files in cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/), a summary of which is listed here for your convenience:
>
> - dbo_mssql.php
> - dbo_mysql.php
> - dbo_mysqli.php
> - dbo_oracle.php
> - dbo_postgres.php
> - **dbo_sqlite.php**

**EDIT:**

http://book.cakephp.org/view/922/Database-Configuration

*Table below code listing.*

**driver** row

> The name of the database driver this configuration array is for. Examples: mysql, postgres, **sqlite**, pear-drivername, adodb-drivername, mssql, oracle, or odbc. Note that for non-database sources (e.g. LDAP, Twitter), leave this blank and use "datasource".

Have you just tried ti set the driver ?

```
var $default = array(
                 'driver'      => 'sqlite',
                 'persistent'  => false,
                 'host'        => 'localhost',
                 'login'       => 'login',
                 'password'    => 'password',
                 'database'    => 'full_path_to_sqlite_file',
                 'prefix'      => ''
);
```

Comment: I found reference to the official sqlite datasource being deprecated and no longer maintained (its sqlite2).

Answer (score 0):

This might a duplicate of [How do I connect CakePHP to a SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021980/cakephp-sqlite)
Also have a look here for more information [Using Sqlite3 with CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722383/using-sqlite3-with-cakephp)

Comment: I made a new question as those were both 1-2 years old, and this is somewhat time sensitive.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit too fast. Have you had a look at this http://trac.cakephp.org/class/dbo-sqlite ?

Comment: I believe that is actually a no longer supported class for SQLite 2.

Answer (score 0):

Digging through the CakePHP tickets it seems the developers won't add Sqlite3 support officially, but encourage the use of this plugin.

https://github.com/cakephp/datasources

Comment: Was this question SQLite 3 specific?

Comment: I wish I knew more about the time-sensitive nature of your question and what it is you need. So far, I'm not sure what you've accomplished, except to establish that SQLite is currently not supported to your liking. :)

Comment: @Jared I mean't time sensitive in the sense that the answers included in the other questions were old. The question was whether or not sqlite was supported (the current version implied), not whether it was supported two years ago.

Comment: You need to be more clear in your question as far as what it is you require/need, and possibly an explanation of what it is you mean to achieve.