# Using SQLite3 with CakePHP 2.0

Tags: cakephp, sqlite, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to run SQLite3 with CakePHP 2.0

In these questions I saw that it's possible to do that in CakePHP 1.3:
- [Using Sqlite3 with CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722383/using-sqlite3-with-cakephp)
- [How do I connect CakePHP to a SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021980/cakephp-sqlite)

However, the solutions are not valid for CakePHP 2.0.

I configured the file 'database.php' and I got success on the starting page of CakePHP. It was able to connect to the database (but I do not know where to find the .db3 database file).

I used the following code:

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Sqlite',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'cake_blog_tutorial',
    'prefix' => '',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

I'm trying to find out:

1. Where should my **cake_blog_tutorial.db3** file be kept
2. Is the datasource different for SQLite3, for example 'Database/Sqlite3'?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: usually is in the webroot folder... try looking there for your file, also i don't know in cake 2.0 since i haven't test it but in 1.3 you need to use sqlite3 since the other one didn't support sqlite3 just previous versions...you may change database to ../cake_blog_tutorial so it appears in your app folder instead of the webroot (to prevent access from outside)

Comment: Thank you, Api55! You answer my question! The file is created automatically in webroot folder (or the other relative folder you choose, like in your example).

CakePHP supports SQLite3, using 'Database/Sqlite'. You can see this opening the lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\Database\Sqlite.php

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In short, the answer is that Sqlite3 databases in CakePHP 2.0 take something like the following configuration:

```
public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Sqlite',
        'persistent' => false,
        'database' => 'database_name',
        'prefix' => '',
        //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

The sqlite file is then automatically created in the webroot directory (unless you prepend a relative path to the database name).

Incidentally, you can use in-memory Sqlite databases (for testing purposes, for example) by changing the database name to ":memory:", e.g.:

```
public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Sqlite',
        'persistent' => false,
        'database' => ':memory:',
        'prefix' => '',
        //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

Comment: This solution is also valid for CakePHP 3