# CakePHP and SQLite: Fatal Error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Tags: cakephp, sqlite

I'm following through the tutorial on the CakePHP website, but decided to use an SQLite database instead. I made a single table and put the database file where the rest of the site files are.

However, when calling ~username/public_html/site/speakers/, I get the following error:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/username/public_html/site/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_sqlite3.php on line 133`

The source code for SpeakersController:

```
<?php
class SpeakersController extends AppController {
  var $name = 'Speakers';
  var $helpers = array ('Html','Form');
  function index(){
      $this->set('speakers', $this->Speaker->find('all'));
}
}
?>
```

Comment: You would need to call the function, `query` on an object, as the error message states. If you post the code, we can help you figure it out if you haven't done so yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the available [core datasources](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/1.3.7/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo), there isn't one called `sqlite3`. I suspect the [database config](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.3.7/app/config/database.php.default#L35) is prompting CakePHP to attempt to load this file. Please check that you have defined your database connection like so:

```
var $default = array(
    'driver' => 'sqlite', // not 'sqlite3'
    'database' => '../database_name.sqlite', // db in /app directory
);
```

---

Okay, this is (now) my understanding of the situation:

- For SQLite 2.x, PHP uses the `sqlite_xxx()` functions provided by PHP's [SQLite database extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php). This is what is currently supported by the core CakePHP `sqlite` datasource. (Note: looking at your comment below, it seems you don't currently have this PHP extension enabled.)
- For SQLite 3.x, PHP uses the `SQLite3()` class provided by PHP's [SQLite3 database extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php). This is unsupported by both the current core CakePHP `sqlite` datasource and the community-provided `sqlite3` datasource.
- However, the community-provided `sqlite3` datasource uses the `PDO()` class provided by PHP's newer [PDO extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) and the [SQLite PDO driver](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php).

So, although unsupported by CakePHP, it looks like you want to use the `sqlite3` driver as to avoid using an unsupported version of SQLite. :)

Anyway, the reason the error in your question appears has been explained in the last comment of the [ticket in Trac](https://trac.cakephp.org/ticket/3003#comment:27) you linked to. The ticket has since been [migrated over to Lighthouse](http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/44-adding-the-unofficial-sqlite-3-driver-for-cakephp-in-next-versions) and marked as `wont-fix`.

The datasource, however, has made it into the community [Datasources plugin](https://github.com/cakephp/datasources) on GitHub, but looks largely [untested](https://github.com/cakephp/datasources/tree/5302f549e8be3029ec87830bd04a12329e5dcf9b/tests/cases/models/datasources/dbo) and the [commit history](https://github.com/cakephp/datasources/commits/master/models/datasources/dbo/dbo_sqlite3.php) doesn't appear to suggest the issue has been fixed.

I would download this latest version of the datasource anyway, but your issue seems to exist specifically because the `new PDO()` call (on what is now [line 167](https://github.com/cakephp/datasources/blob/3574bab98f9bdc60ffa5f86d3c08e4a96d664b54/models/datasources/dbo/dbo_sqlite3.php#L167)) doesn't return a `PDO` object because it fails to connect to the database.

Hopefully this should give you a starting point for debugging the problem. Try sprinkling in a `debug($this->config); debug($this->connection);` to inspect what is going wrong.

Comment: I had downloaded the sqlite3 patch per here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021980/cakephp-sqlite but using the default sqlite, I get this error instead: `Call to undefined function sqlite_query()`

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you don't have sqlite enabled for php. Try this:
install sqlite3:

```
sudo aptitude install sqlite3
```

install php5-sqlite

```
sudo aptitude install php5-sqlite
```